# How do I access elements from the outer loop from within nested loops?

Tags: xslt, scope, for-loop

I have nested xsl:for loops:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Root/A">
    <xsl:for-each select="/Root/B">
        <!-- Code -->
    </xsl:for>
</xsl:for>
```

**From within the inner loop, how can I access attributes from the current node in the outer loop?**

I keep finding myself writing code like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Root/A">
    <xsl:variable name="someattribute" select="@SomeAttribute"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="/Root/B">
        <!-- Now can use $someattribute to access data from 'A' -->
    </xsl:for>
</xsl:for>
```

This doesn't scale very well, as sometimes I need to access several pieces of information and end up creating one variable for each piece.  Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can store the entire /Root/A structure in a variable, and make reference to that variable rather than creating a new variable for every attribute and subelement you need to access.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Root/A/">
    <xsl:variable name="ROOT_A" select="."/>
    <xsl:for-each select="/Root/B/">
         <!-- Variable is accessed like this: $ROOT_A/@someAttribute
              Just like a normal XML node -->
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: +1, but it might be worth editing the variable name to make its function more clear.

Comment: That's what I usually end up doing ;-p

Answer (score 8):

[Welbog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52443/welbog) has answered it well - but just to note you appear to be doing a cartesion (cross) join - is that intentional? If you are trying to do a regular join (with a predicate etc), then you want want to look into `<xsl:key/>` - i.e. declare a key:

```
<xsl:key name="BIndex" match="/Root/B" use="SomeChildNode"/>
```

then consume in your predicate:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Root/A/">
    <xsl:variable name="ROOT_A" select="."/>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('BIndex', LocalNode)">
     <!-- -->
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This should be equivalent to (but much faster than) the predicate:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="/Root/B[SomeChildNode = current()/LocalNode]">
```

If you are *grouping* the data, then look at [Muenchian grouping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muenchian_grouping)

Comment: Thanks for the tips..  I'm relatively new to XSLT and aren't completely sure what I'm doing yet.  Once I get things working I'll take a look at what you suggest to see if there's an easier way.

Comment: Note: It took me some effort to decipher the 'cartesian-join vs. predicate-join part' above. So just noting down the difference for people new to it.  
Basically if you have a 'm' number of nodes in A and 'n' number of nodes in B, cartesian join will result in m*n nodes whereas predicate-join joins on a particular key i.e. join A AND B where A.key = B.key.

Comment: To check against the element name of current (the element the for-loop iterates over), you can use  `name(current())` - don't try `current()/name()`, it's not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The following could also be used :

```
    <xsl:for-each select="ns:attribute">
        <name><xsl:value-of select="ns:name" /></name>              
        <xsl:for-each select="ns:value">
        <value><xsl:value-of select="."/></value>       
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

For parsing the XML document ..

```
 <ns:attribute>
      <ns:name>name</ns:name>
      <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
      <ns:value>Rahul</ns:value>
      <ns:value>Sushovan</ns:value>
</ns:attribute>
```