# XSLT For-each in for-each position()

Tags: xslt

I have a trouble with a position in XSLT, I will explain what I'm doing.

I have a for each into another for each, like this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="tagA">
   <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
       <xsl:for-each select="tagB">
           <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
       </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

EDIT 1 :

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<main>
<tagA>
<row>
 <info>
 tag A pos one
 </info>
</row>
<row>
 <info>
 tag A pos two
 </info>
</row>
<tagB>
<rowB posB="reference of tag A pos One">
<rowB posB="reference of tag A pos Two">
</tagB>
</main>
```

XSL :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/main">
  <xsl:for-each select="tagA">
       <xsl:for-each select="tagB">
           <xsl:if test="//tagA/info = 'tag A pos one'">
             HERE I WANT TAG A POSITION
           </xsl:if>
       </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its something like that, the question is: How can I get "tagA" position value in tagB select?

Sorry for my bad English, and I hope you can help me.

Thanks you for advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nested for-each loops, accessing outer element with variable from the inner loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436237/nested-for-each-loops-accessing-outer-element-with-variable-from-the-inner-loop)

Comment: Declare a variable and store position() before the inner for-each.. And then use its value inside the for-each..

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable here

```
<xsl:for-each select="tagA">
   <xsl:variable name="tagAPosition" select="position()"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="$tagAPosition" />
   <xsl:for-each select="tagB">
       <xsl:value-of select="$tagAPosition" />
        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

So, the value of `$tagAPosition` is the same both outside and inside the `tagB` loop.

Comment: I already tried it, but it show me all time "1" (And my for each contains 2 rows)

Comment: It would help if you edited your question to show your XML, and your expected output. Thanks.

Comment: The XML you show only has one `tagA` and one `tagB`, so that is why `position` is 1 for both. It looks like you are more interested in the `row` elements. Rather than try and explain how you are trying to solve it, can you show exactly what output you want? Also, make sure your XML is well-formed (and also representative of your actual XML), as the structure is important. Thanks!