# xsl use value of select to select another value in a loop

Tags: php, xslt

I am trying to convert the following php code into xslt.

```
$columns =  [a,b,c];
$records = [[a,b,c][a,b,c][a,b,c]];

foreach($records as $records){
  echo "<tr>";
  foreach($columns as $col){
    echo $records[$col];
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

In xsl I have got the following

```
                            <thead>
                                <xsl:for-each select="/response/body/recordset/columns">
                                    <th>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
                                    </th>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </thead>
                            <xsl:for-each select="/response/body/recordset/record">
                                <xsl:variable name="journeyDetails" select="."/>
                                <tr>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="/response/body/recordset/columns">
                                        <td>                                            
                                            <xsl:value-of /><xsl:attribute name="select">$journeyDetails/<xsl:value-of select="current()"/></xsl:attribute>
                                        </td>
                                    </xsl:for-each>

                                </tr>

                            </xsl:for-each>
```

It is not working for me, i get a blank page. I believe the xsl for loop is wrong. I have tried to use examples from here, [How do I access elements from the outer loop from within nested loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453258/how-do-i-access-elements-from-the-outer-loop-from-within-nested-loops)

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/xslt/user_audit_view.xsl"?>
<response>
  <header>
  </header>
  <body>
    <recordset>
      <record>
        <ID>201</ID>
        <O_ENTITY_ID>1</O_ENTITY_ID>
        <O_LOCATION_ID></O_LOCATION_ID>
        <O_NAME>sharif</O_NAME>
        <O_CREATED_BY>UddinS2</O_CREATED_BY>
        <O_UPDATED_BY>UddinS2</O_UPDATED_BY>
        <N_ENTITY_ID></N_ENTITY_ID>
        <N_LOCATION_ID></N_LOCATION_ID>
        <N_NAME></N_NAME>
        <N_CREATED_BY></N_CREATED_BY>
        <N_UPDATED_BY></N_UPDATED_BY>
        <ACTION>DELETE</ACTION>
        <USERNAME>test</USERNAME>
        <TABLE_ID>181</TABLE_ID>
        <O_TS_CREATED>28-Jun-17 10:36:53</O_TS_CREATED>
        <N_TS_CREATED></N_TS_CREATED>
        <TS_CREATED>28-Jun-17 15:48:45</TS_CREATED>
      </record>
     <columns>ID</columns>
      <columns>O_ENTITY_ID</columns>
      <columns>O_LOCATION_ID</columns>
      <columns>O_NAME</columns>
      <columns>O_CREATED_BY</columns>
      <columns>O_UPDATED_BY</columns>
      <columns>O_TS_CREATED</columns>
      <columns>N_ENTITY_ID</columns>
      <columns>N_LOCATION_ID</columns>
      <columns>N_NAME</columns>
      <columns>N_CREATED_BY</columns>
      <columns>N_UPDATED_BY</columns>
      <columns>N_TS_CREATED</columns>
      <columns>ACTION</columns>
      <columns>USERNAME</columns>
      <columns>TABLE_ID</columns>
      <columns>TS_CREATED</columns>
    </recordset>
  </body>
</response>
```

I am trying to generate a table dynamically so that i can use this stylesheet on similar data. i am passing in columns which will be thead in table and records are the data in the tbody. i want to be able to place each column value for each record under the correct column heading without explicitly specifying the column name in the stylesheet.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a sample of your input XML? Thanks!

Comment: added xml sample

Answer (score 1):

The expression you are after is this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="$journeyDetails/*[name() = current()]" />
```

i.e. Find the child element of the $journeyDetails node which has the same name as the current column value.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="/response/body/recordset/columns">
        <th>
          <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
        </th>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <xsl:for-each select="/response/body/recordset/record">
      <xsl:variable name="journeyDetails" select="."/>
      <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="/response/body/recordset/columns">
          <td>                                            
            <xsl:value-of select="$journeyDetails/*[name() = current()]" />
          </td>
        </xsl:for-each>      
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:value-of /><xsl:attribute name="select">$journeyDetails/<xsl:value-of select="current()"/></xsl:attribute>
```

I think you've developed a completely wrong mental model of how this language works. I think you are trying to use xsl:attribute, not to create an attribute node in the result tree, but to create an attribute in the stylesheet itself, in the hope that this attribute will then be evaluated and the result added to the result tree.

XSLT is like most modern programming languages: you can't modify the program during the course of execution.

With XSLT 3.0 you *can* construct XPath expressions dynamically from strings and evaluate them: the syntax for that is the xsl:evaluate instruction. Some XSLT processors prior to XSLT 3.0 have vendor extensions that do similar things. I very much doubt that you need that capability here. But without knowing what your input and output are supposed to look like, it's rather hard to advise. (Your only requirements statement is a piece of PHP code and I don't know PHP).